# Change back ground colour when animation is playing

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

**Blender 3.6.7LTS**

When I trigger play animation I would like a **script** to change the background to a reddish colour To indicate that the animation is playing and when I stop the animation player it defaults to it's original colour.

I tried to chat GTP this, but to no avail.

**My basic logic was**

1. Deafult =
   bpy.context.space_data.shading.background_type = 'THEME'
2. When animation is playing change bpy.context.space_data.shading.background_type = 'VIEWPORT'
   and make it's colour bpy.context.space_data.shading.background_color = (0.0169089, 0.00796443, 0.00961567)
3. When animation player has stopped, revert back to default.

Chat GTP can do the first 50%, it's fails knowing when the animation player has stopped, or my instructions are terrible.

**I want this because sometimes the animation is playing in the background by mistake and it'll crunch my computer if I'm in weight mapping etc.**

Comment: Or the simple version is, you change the shortcut for playing animations to something you do not click so easily by accident or remove the shortcut completely... just an idea because I know nothing about python scripting. That's why I filter out questions tagged with "python" or "scripting". Now the only thing that's left is people asking for python scripts would actually use matching tags for their questions ;-)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: time for you to learn it ;) you miss A LOT of possibilities. And since you know GN and shader nodes, you already have half the knowledge ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I agree with the tagging, I will remember for the future. For the work around, in an ideal world their would be no innovation on the workaround if we were to never to have accidents. :D

Comment: @Chris The last months the only times I get to do something in Blender is when I try to solve problems from other users here on BSE. No time to learn something new  But working with nodes helped me with ComfyUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

version for Blender 3.6.7

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Active Background",
    "author": "Blender.Fun",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Changes background when animation is playing.",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Themes",
}

import bpy



def start(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    
def stop(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    
    
   
def register(): 
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(start)

    
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.remove(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.remove(start)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

works for Blender 4.20:

insert this into your text editor:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Active Background",
    "author": "Blender.Fun",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Changes background when animation is playing.",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Themes",
}

import bpy



def my_handler(scene):
    
    print("is in handler")
    
    if bpy.context.screen.is_animation_playing:
        bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    else:
        bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    
    
def register(): 
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(my_handler)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(my_handler)

    
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.remove(my_handler)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.remove(my_handler)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Run the script.

Enjoy :)

[image]

Comment: Don't do nothing for me, https://youtu.be/AIRBo31RyUw

Comment: ok, i am just downloading 3.67....give me 10 mins i think there was an API change

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks dude! I owe you one. Internet hug!

Comment: Any idea why it's not persistent on re-loading blender?

Comment: yes, i know why that is - but please ask a new question and don't "append" further questions in comments. You may ask as many questions as you like. But other people won't find your "comment"-questions, because BSE doesn't consider questions in comments. thx.