# Change back ground colour when animation is playing - Part 2

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

Following up from [Part 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314777/change-back-ground-colour-when-animation-is-playing?noredirect=1#comment545908_314777) I'm looking to see about making this persistent when (re)loading up blender 3.6.7, Much thanks to [Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris) for writing something that works when inside the text editor.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Active Background",
    "author": "Blender.Fun",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Changes background when animation is playing.",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Themes",
}

import bpy



def start(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    
def stop(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    
    
   
def register(): 
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(start)

    
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.remove(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.remove(start)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Active Background",
    "author": "Blender.Fun",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Changes background when animation is playing.",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Themes",
}

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def start(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
 
@persistent   
def stop(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    
    
def register(): 
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(start)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.remove(stop)
    bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.remove(start)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

copy this code in your text editor, save the text with text-> save as

[image]

and use any name with ".py" at the end.

Then go to your add-ons preferences, press install, choose that py file.

Done.

Comment: Thanks, and enjoy the free coffee :D

Comment: thank you very much!!!